# Trying to predict the random.shuffle result in Python

Tags: python, prediction

For a class projet, i want to be able to predict the result of a random.shuffle, but what i learned about the random module is way more advance than everything i learned so far.
Do you have any idea of how it could be done ?

I found some code that allowed me to predict the result of randint, but nothing for shuffle

Comment: What do you mean predict ? Get a few values and predict the next one or start from nothing and always get the same values ?

Comment: You can try to set the seed, using the `random.seed()` method, then it should always give the same result

Answer (score 1):

The following code should always give the same output:

```
lst = [0,1,2,3,4]
random.seed(5)
random.shuffle(lst)
print(lst)
```

My guess is that if you managed to make it work for other methods, you simply forgot to reinitialize the list each time